# django-require and require-cs

Tags: django, coffeescript, requirejs

Has anybody successfully used [django-require](https://github.com/etianen/django-require) and [require-cs](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs) together?

I get stuck when deploying the application. I want coffee files to be compiled into JS and coffee-script.js excluded from the build.

I added my own build profile (using REQUIRE_BUILD_PROFILE) and used [this build file](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs/blob/master/demo/build.js) as an example, but it doesn't seem to work.

Yeah, if you could post your build.js and settings.py, that'd be great ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use coffeescript with requirejs, you need to load your coffeescript files using the cs! loader plugin.

For example, given a file structure like this:

- js

  - main.js  // Main script file, just a minimal javascript stub.
  - cs.js  // Coffeescript loader plugin.
  - coffee-script.js  // Coffeescript compiler.
  - csmain.coffee  // Your actual coffeescript main file.
  - module1.coffee  // A coffeescript module.
  - module2.coffee  // Another coffeescript module.
  - app.build.js  // App build profile.

Then, in your main.js file, you can bootstrap your coffeescript app like this:

```
require(["cs!csmain"])
```

Your csmain.coffee file can then run your app, something like this:

```
require([
    "cs!module1",
    "cs!module2"
], (module1, module2) ->
    module1.doSomething
    module2.doSomething
```

A build profile like this should then take care of optimization:

```
({
    stubModules: ['cs'],
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'main',
            exclude: ['coffee-script']
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Coffeescript and requirejs work nicely together. To problem occurs when I run Django's collectstatic: require.storage.OptimizationError: Error while running r.js optimizer
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

which I assume is due to some path problems.